# Using Copy Directory Helper in Codeigniter to copy and move files

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am using this [copy directory](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/copy_directory/) helper addon for the directory helper to help me copy files to different places on my web server.

It works perfectly if the files you are copying from and the folder you are copying to are located within the CodeIgniter install directory.

I however have my codeigniter installation in a subdirectory (http://domain.com/site) and would like to be able to move and copy directories in the root directory.

```
directory_copy('./user_guide/', './test_copy/');
```

Creates test_copy and copies the contents of user_guide to it.

However doing this (NOTICE the missing DOT( . ) in the destination directory)

```
directory_copy('./user_guide/', '/test_copy/');
```

Causes

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied

Filename: helpers/directory_helper.php

Line Number: 91
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

Filename: helpers/directory_helper.php

Line Number: 91
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: copy(/test_copy/helpers/cookie_helper.html) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: helpers/directory_helper.php

Line Number: 99
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: copy(/test_copy/helpers/string_helper.html) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: helpers/directory_helper.php

Line Number: 99
```

...etc for each file in the directory.

I have checked all permissions and they seem fine. It seems the script can’t execute outside of the CI installation.

All help or advice would be appreciated

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `.` (dot) is simply refer to server root `/`,
which require **root user permission** for adding new folder.
User running apache does not have enough permission in this case.

Simply copy to another folder that apache user able to access and has write permission.

Comment: Hello, I have tried your suggestion but even going to another sub directory doesn't work. So copying from http://domain.com/folder to http://domain.com/folder2 doesnt work... Surely I have enough permissions to do this... especially as I am able to successfully copy and move files withnin my CI installation "/folder"???

Comment: @Tim - Please use absolute path for destination folder ... like the code your showing, is using relative path which is point to `/` .. double check ? Otherwise, understand what CI copy function does ...

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion led me onto the right track. Using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] finally got me going!!! Cheers and have a good night!

Answer (score 0):

> application/config/config.php

Try adding the below line:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;

$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```